# My SSIS files wont open

Tags: visual-studio, bids

I opened BIDS and then tried to click the highlighted file that I was working on this morning.
But the Properties and the Field Explorer is blank. Please see the image below.

[image]

When I try to open a new project >> analysis services4 >> it is still blank.

[image]

I have already restarted my laptop and I have an internet connection. So what's wrong with my BIDS?

When I check the package itself, when I double click it. It is still blank. Please see the two screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

When I close and re-open it, it prompts me that there is not internet connection. If theres none how can I post this problem in Stack overflow in the first place.

[image]

Comment: may be you have opened aspx.cs

Comment: I can't see all the shots, but in the one that does display, you don't have a solution explorer up?  bids wont change its look until you actually click on one of the items...

Comment: Ever since that I started using BIDS, solution explorer has been always up. But this time, it's gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select `View -> Solution Explorer`. Your project should be loaded there. Once you will open a file, other explorers and windows will change accordingly.